# How can I recover Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu on a dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

EDIT: As a reply to @cocomac, I included the screenshot of the partitions, here it is:

[my disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vAvq.png)

I really have no idea how can I recover windows. I really appreciate any help.

---

Here's my story...
I purchased a computer with Windows 10 on it. That time, I'm learning Linux, and I decided to install Ubuntu on my machine on dual-boot instead of Virtualbox as I want a more seamless experience (it's laggy on Virtualbox). Since I'm new to dual booting, I just followed a tutorial on YouTube, and I successfully dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.
But that's not the ending, as I try to explore Linux distros and me being so naive of these entire process, but too arrogant to just try a bunch of things, I tried to triple boot my computer and installed Kali Linux. Here's when things got messed up. First, I successfully installed Kali Linux, and I can boot into it. Then I tried to switch back to Ubuntu from Kali. And from there, Ubuntu to Windows. Here's when the problem arise. I can't boot into Windows 10. I'm always redirected to Ubuntu and I have no idea why. That's when I removed Kali from my machine to see if that's the problem but it persists. Now, I can only boot into Ubuntu.

Is there any chance of recovering my Windows 10?

Comment: When you boot up, before it loads GRUB (that's where you select the OS to boot to), you can access a boot menu, typically by pressing one of the function keys. You'd have to look it up for your specific device. In the boot menu, see if there is an option like "Windows Boot Manager". If there is, select it. That should boot to Windows. If it isn't there, boot to Ubuntu, open GParted, and take a screenshot and add it to your post. That will let us see if you can get back to Windows. Windows may have been removed from the menu, which is fixable. If, however, you overwrote Windows, that is harder.

Comment: Last system to install or do major update will be first in boot order in UEFI. And last system to install will have the grub that is in control. You have to manage which grub you want as default boot & may have to reset it if another system updates. And all systems must be installed in same boot mode or all UEFI or all old BIOS. Most systems now are UEFI.

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`, and check if Windows 10 now shows up in the grub-menu.

Comment: @cocomac thanks for the help. I apologize for taking me so long to respond. Anyway, I tried looking for the "Windows Boot Manager" on the boot menu as you said, but I didn't find it. So as you instructed, I took a screenshot of my disk partition, linked in this post. I really appreciate your help, and I sincerely thank you for that.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thanks for the response. I tried it but I didn't find Windows 10.

Comment: In that case, you will most likely have to reinstall Windows (which will corrupt the Ubuntu boot menu), and then recover Ubuntu (it may be easier to reinstall Ubuntu afterward). At this point, decide whether you really need Windows before you proceed to reinstall (otherwise, leave Ubuntu as it is). Also, Kali is not designed to be used as a general purpose operating system, and should not be used by beginners. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)